# How to connect php app to compose for mysql on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: php

I currently working on PHP app which is run on blumix and I have used the following code to connected to this app to Compose for MySQL.But the connection has failed and shown me an error message on the browser "  lastapp.eu-gb.mybluemix.net is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

the code below has been used to create the connection.
enter link description here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUwCD.png)

Comment: Are you able to connect successfully?  What have you already tried?  You will get a good response if you edit your question to include your code and any problems you are having.  Not very many people will want to write the code for you, but you could try the MySQL example here: https://github.com/compose-grandtour/php

Comment: Thanks for your  reply Lorna, I  have used the following code to connected   which is exactly that used in the example above :

Comment: <?php



$connection_string = 'mysql://admin:FWXJWBNMHRFNUOVG@sl-eu-lon-2-portal.11.dblayer.com:27707/compose';
// $dbname = 'compose'; // optional, supply this if the name isn't in the URL

$db = parse_url($connection_string);

$db = parse_url($connection_string);
// try to get the dbname from the URL, but extra variable takes precedence
$db['dbname'] = substr($db['path'],1);
unset($db['path']); // not needed
if(isset($dbname) && $dbname) {
    $db['dbname'] = $dbname;
}

Comment: I following the example -mysql that found in the following link https://github.com/compose-grandtour/php .but right now i have the connection problem ,please I am looking for help.

Comment: Note, I  run on blumix without any localhost.

Comment: First of all, please don’t post extended code snippets in comments, that is hard to read. Edit your question instead. (Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/286047 first.) Secondly, properly describe what specific problem you are having. _“but right now i have the connection problem”_ - what is “the” connection problem supposed to be? Please go read [ask] as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advise I will edit it.

Comment: Using your provided credentials (:D) I could connect to your database when removing the `/compose` from the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel, I did remove it but it still the same.@DanielBürckner

Comment: @DanielBürckner, cloud you show me please how you managed to access to the DB, please.

Comment: See my answer @يوسفالصغير

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing this code I could connect to your database:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("sl-eu-lon-2-portal.11.dblayer.com", "admin", "FWXJWBNMHRFNUOVG", "compose", 27707);

if (!$conn) {
  echo "Error!";
  die();
}
else {
  echo "Success!<br>";
  echo "Details: ".mysqli_get_host_info($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Please, do you run it inside the PHP app on bluemix or on localhost, because when I tried on bluemix shown the same error :-  @ Danial ,  .I am greatful for your help.

Comment: @ Daniel Bürckner  ,I have tesed the code on localhost  is able to access to the db but on bulimix  show the same error .please where you tried on blumix or ???

Comment: I tested it from my server (not Bluemix). I suggest you enable PHP `error_reporting` and have a look at the log files to narrow down the error. @يوسفالصغير